# How to intercept http/https requests done by an Android app in plain text?

Tags: android, sniffer, packet

When I give an android app internet permission and read access to my files, malicious software can send my personal data (pictures and video) to a remote server without me being aware of it.

Is there a way I can intercept all the request done by an app on Android?
I am looking for something similar to what postman interceptor does on a browser, but instead, I am to listen to the app's requests. (Or chrome developer console, Network tab)

Answer (score 2):

Using a packet capture tool like the other answers suggest will give you the raw network traffic, but will not help decrypt HTTPS traffic. 
For that you will probably need to install a certificate and change all traffic to use that certificate.
Tools like Burp Suite are used for this:
https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp

Also, this will only work if the app doesn't do cerificate pinning, for those you might have to decompile the app into smali, remove pinning and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Android PCAP](https://www.kismetwireless.net/android-pcap/) which require android 4.0 or above.

or if the phone is already rooted you can use `bitshark`. its generated PCAP can be used to analyze in Wireshark